# How does Django handle cancelled or interrupted requests?

Tags: python, django

Let's say for my django application, I submit a request via the browser. In the middle of the processing, it creates a local resource (e.g., a file), which will be deleted at the end of the request.

Now to throw a wrench into things. After my request has created the resource, but before deletion, I cancel the request in my browser. Does django still complete the request and delete the resource? Is there any way within the django code to know when the client connection has been closed, perhaps with some kind of signal?

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel the request in my browser", once you've sent a request, the browsers job is done, it just waits for a response. There is no connection

Comment: So this probably answers my question then. If it is sitting there waiting for a response, and I cancel that, nothing happens on the django side. It will just complete the request, and attempt to return it. Is there still a way to check if the client connection is still alive within django, or is that outside of django's scope?

Comment: Its outside of django's scope, If you're trying to do long running tasks then perhaps you are looking for celery.

Comment: Are you sure there is no connection? There should be a connection until the response is received by the client... Here[1] is an explanation of why Django does not get notified of the disconnection of the client until the end of the request handling. Taking this into account, I guess maybe you could use [2] to test if the connection was dropped, but I think it would be a dreadful idea even if it worked.

[1]: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/3ksj4Clne4c
[2]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects